# How do I change Concrete5's attitude toward my markup?

Tags: html, content-management-system, markup, concrete5

Concrete5.

I have a span. I want to 'name' it and 'class' it. I edit the code HTML and put

```
<span name='Nameo' class='Classo'>...</span>
```

I save it and re-edit it. I see

```
<span class='Classo'>...</span>
```

Where's my 'name' gone? Is there any way I can tell Concrete5 to leave my name alone?

Comment: Sometimes CMS's don't strip **extra** attributes out until you open it for re-editing~ I would check to see if it is saving it properly

Comment: Tried that. Not the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: There is no [name attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) for span elements. It looks like Concrete5 is fixing your error for you. It's generally a good idea to write real HTML.

Comment: It's TinyMCE that is fixing the error, not Concrete5 (kind of a nitpick, but it will help in solving the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the "Content" block here. The only altering of this content that C5 does is for url's to internal pages and files (so links in your content don't break when you change servers / domain names / subdirectories). I'm guessing this is actually something the TinyMCE editor is doing. I don't think "name" is a valid attribute on a span so TinyMCE is probably stripping it out.

See this TinyMCE FAQ for more details:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_strip_away_attributes_or_tags_from_my_source.3F